# In R, how to bin multiple variables

Tags: r, vector, statistics, histogram, binning

In R, how to bin multiple variables
I am using the hist function in R to capture mids (midpoints) and counts.

***I would like to get the bin, number of breaks, mids(midpoints) and counts in these situations:***

1. Get the value of the mids and counts where the vector A is the overall data and vector B is the subset of vector A (there can be NAs in vector B)
2. The vector A has some values intersecting with vector B.
3. Vector A is completely different in vector B
4. Vector A is identical to vector B

**Note: the midpoints and bins should be properly computed for use with the hist function or other package that can be helpful for this problem.

***Input dataset are numbers. Example: vector A = {1,20,30,15}; vector B = {1,NA,30,15} (For subset)***

I would like to have a table with columns like:

```
row_num, mids (midpoints), vectorAcnts (A counts), vectorBcnts (B counts)
1, 3, 3, 2
2, 6, 0, 1
3, 9, 1, 1
```

Other relevant to get are Bin width, number of breaks.

Comment: Where is the input dataset?

Comment: Input dataset are numbers. Example: vector A = 1,20,30,15; vector B = 1,NA,30,15